# Remove parenthesis after setting index using pandas

Tags: pandas

Pandas' `set_index` function changed my index `PATIENT_ID` into a string with parentheses `()`. How do I remove the parentheses?

```
# Clinical patient info
raw_clinical_patient = pd.read_csv("./gbm_tcga/data_clinical_patient.txt", sep="\t", header=4).drop(labels="OTHER_PATIENT_ID", axis=1)
raw_clinical_patient = raw_clinical_patient.sort_index()

# Clinical sample info
raw_clinical_sample = pd.read_csv("./gbm_tcga/data_clinical_sample.txt", sep="\t", header=4).drop(labels=["OTHER_SAMPLE_ID"], axis=1)
raw_clinical_sample = raw_clinical_sample.sort_index()

# Merge dataframes 
raw_clin = pd.concat([raw_clinical_sample, raw_clinical_patient])

# Drop "PATIENT_ID" and rename "SAMPLE_ID" as "PATIENT_ID" and set as index
raw_clin.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
raw_clin.rename(columns={'SAMPLE_ID':'PATIENT_ID'}, inplace=True)
raw_clin.set_index("PATIENT_ID", inplace=True)
raw_clin
```

Current output

| PATIENT_ID | Another header | Another header |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (First) | row | row |
| (Second) | row | row |

Desired output:

| PATIENT_ID | Another header | Another header |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | row |
| Second | row | row |

Comment: Add you sure this is a string?

Answer (score 0):

If the parentheses are always present in first and last position you can use:

```
df['PATIENT_ID'] = df['PATIENT_ID'].str[1:-1]
```

Or

```
df['PATIENT_ID'] = df['PATIENT_ID'].str.strip('()')
```

Comment: `raw_clin['PATIENT_ID'].str[1:-1]` raised `if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:`. I think the error was raised because `PATIENT_ID` is index and not column name.